# Mock function not being called with react-testing-library, but original function is called

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have, I think, a simple case. I am using a function in my component that is imported from a different file. I've mocked the function as shown below. I've also tried adding a mock implementation, but that didn't work either. If I put a print statement in my original function, that appears when I run the test. If I understand correctly, a mock should replace the original.

I've tried to make this as straightforward as possible, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

test file:

```
import AddStoryModal from './AddStoryModal';
import addStory from '../api/add_story';

jest.mock('../api/add_story');

describe('Story tests', () => {

  it('makes an API call to add a story', () => {
    render(<AddStoryModal />);

    const submitButton = screen.getByTestId('add-submit');  
    fireEvent.click(submitButton);
    expect(addStory).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

result:

```
 expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

component being tested:

```
...
import addStory from '../api/add_story';

function AddStoryModal(){

  const onFinish = (values) => {
    addStory();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button type="primary" data-testid="add-story" onClick={showModal}>
        Create New +
      </Button>

      <Modal title="Add New Story ..." visible={visible} data-testid='add-story-modal' onCancel={handleCancel} footer={null}>
        <Form form={form} layout="vertical" onFinish={onFinish}>
          ...
          <Form.Item>
            <Button type="primary" data-testid="add-submit" htmlType="submit">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice example of how writing tests can make your production code better. Yes, you *could* continue with using `jest.mock(*module*)` and work out what's going wrong, but *why*?

Have a look at what `AddStoryModal` is actually doing. It's very coupled to calling the API function, which in turn is what is making testing awkward.

If you **pass the `onFinish` implementation function as a prop** you immediately get some great wins:

- Less code in `AddStoryModal`
- It becomes more versatile (and increases the chances of being reused)
- It becomes easier to test

`AddStoryModal`:

```
function AddStoryModal(props) {
  return (
   <>
  ...
        <Form form={form} layout="vertical" onFinish={props.onFinish}>
  ...
    </>
  );
}
```

Now it knows nothing about `../api/add_story`

And your test becomes:

```
import AddStoryModal from './AddStoryModal';

describe('Story tests', () => {
  it('makes an API call to add a story', () => {
    const finishCallback = jest.fn();

    render(<AddStoryModal onFinish={finishCallback} />);

    const submitButton = screen.getByTestId('add-submit');
    fireEvent.click(submitButton);
    expect(finishCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Super-clean test, easy to understand, and a better overall fit for the React way.

In your production code, whatever page was using `<AddStoryModal />` now just uses `<AddStoryModal onFinish={addStory} />`

Comment: Thanks @millhouse. Did the refactoring you suggested, and created a simplified component, but even so, I get the same failure that the mock function is never called.

Comment: OK well then it sounds like you've found a bug then! FYI I tested this by just creating a simple `button` in `AddStoryModal` and assigned `onClick={props.onFinish}` - and that worked. So I'd go looking at how your `Form` fires its `onFinish` callback - is there something not right there, or is there form validation that is running when the submit button is pressed, that results in the `onFinish` callback not firing?

Comment: Good thought. I'll look into that. It is odd that if I put a `console.log` in `addStory`, it does run. In some world, this is `onFinish` is succeeding. I'll post if/when I sort it out. Thanks.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm treating this like a behavioral test, but the event that I want to happen is actually a `submit` not a `click`. Thanks for your help!